# Coded UI : How to skip a test case

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

Let say I have multiple test case: TC1, TC2, TC3, TC4

If TC2 failed, I wanna skip TC3 and move on to TC4 instead.

I know there is 'Continue After Failure' in Ordered Test, but that function will just continue to TC3.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can organize one `ordered test` inside another. Combine TC2 and TC3 in one `ordered test` and set it NOT to continue on failure. Then pack this `ordered test` inside your bigger one, which should continue on failure. Your main `ordered test` will look like:

- TC1
- `OrderedTest-TC2-TC3`
- TC4